# Concurrent program in C(sequential issue)

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, fork, system-calls

I am trying to find a way to make this algorithm run concurrent and be simultaneous. So far it has only 1 for-loop that reads each file and then makes a process for each file.

I believe this algorithm runs sequentially which is not what I want... 
I thought about creating an outer for-loop where I put the wait(null) and read command. But when I tried it did not work, didn't produce output. Currently I have the wait(null) command in the parent process.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   // ATTRIBUTES //
   int freq[argc-1], ipc[argc][2], nbytes, i;// freq of words, pipes, counters
   ssize_t errorfi;
   char  readbuffer[9999];
   char** k = malloc(50);
   char** op = malloc(50);


   if(argc == ONE) { // there are no files given, throw error and close
     fprintf(stderr, "There are no files found from %s\n", argv[0]);
     exit(0);
   }

  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) // creates pipes for ipc
     pipe(ipc[i]);

  pid_t pids[argc-1]; // array of pids
  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) { // reads input after position 0(a.out)

      pid_t pid = fork(); // creates process
      pids[i-1] = pid;
      if( pid < 0 ) {       // bad fork process: error
         perror("bad fork");
         exit(0);
      }
      else if(pid > 0) {   //parent process

         close(ipc[i][1]);
         wait(NULL);
         nbytes = read(ipc[i][0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

        if(nbytes > 0)
          printf("%s\n", readbuffer);
      }
      else if(pid == 0) {  // child process

           close(ipc[i][0]);

           k = inputReader(argv[i]); // finds filename,w1,w2,w3,uniqueWords

           char info[50] = "";

           strcat(info, k[0]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[1]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[2]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[3]);
           strcat(info, " ");
           strcat(info, k[4]);

           int uniqueWordint = atoi(k[4]);
           freq[i-1] = uniqueWordint; // freq of all uniqueWords

           errorfi = write(ipc[i][1], info, strlen(info)+1); // writes info to pipe i

           if (errorfi < 0 ) {

              fprintf(stderr, "error found when writing in pipe errofi: %d\n", errorfi);
              exit(0);
           }

          exit(0); // close process
      } // closes child process
   } // closes for-loop for each process

   for(j = 0; j < argc-1; j++) {
        wait(2); // if i put read command here it won't work
   }
   return(0); // close main 
 }
```

Comment: You are `strcat()`ing to an uninitialised array of char `char info[50];` provoking undefined behaviour. Change the latter to be `char info[50] ="";`.

Comment: @geforce: This is unrelated to this question, but I see that you deleted your previous question "using pthreads to concurretly find words in a file in C". I fixed some of your code before you deleted it: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/83338defb71302c4ce36 . It's still really ugly and doesn't work for all edge cases, but at least you shouldn't get any more segfaults.

Comment: Thanks for trying... but it still crashes on dataset2.txt and now this time it doesn't print the correct output for dataset1.txt

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for that edited code. I was able to review based off your code and fix something in my main function so now it all works correctly and is sorted. In addition, i'm getting rid of arrays and replacing with pointers.

Comment: In addition, the ACTUAL problem was in findWords()... and it was my array allWords it did not have enough memory which is why the other textfiles didn't work. After debugging I learned this was the issue so I made it a pointer and set it much more memory @TimM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much a sequential execution indeed. The parent-process enters a loop, forks a child-process, and then it won't continue to the next loop until that child-process is done.

What you could do is create a `pid_t` array of size `argc`, to store each `fork()`'s return value.
Also create a new loop after "for-loop for each process", where the parent-process would wait for all of his children, using [`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) or [`waitpid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), depending on whether you need to process each child's result in the specific order or not, and continue processing them (`read`ing or whatever needed.

Comment: I edited my program and did that but it doesn't work for some reason. Because if i move the read command outside of parent process it doesnt work... i uploaded my edited code above

Comment: Also what do i do with the array of pids? Do i check the return value before reading?